# Regex: Convert the first lowercase letter of the starting words into capital Letter (after .dot)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this case:

`My sister is home. she loves music. And I don't have a stereo.`

I want to find all the words that comes after the dot and start with a lowercase letter in all my lines, and convert that lowercase letter into capital letter in all similar cases from all lines.

**The output:**

`My sister is home. She loves music. And I don't have a stereo.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.(\s)([a-z])`
- Replace with: `.\x20\u$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>